Can I write a robots.txt rule to forbid crawling URLs with an anchor part (using the hash character, #)?
I have a table of content plugin on my site which made some URLs with # at the beginning.
like: https://example.com/#how_to_do_something which links to that header's part in the content.
Its like it made different URL for every header in my content to be able to link them with table of content, so that if user clicks on that header in table of content, navigates to that part.
Anyway, I wanted to disallow these URLs in robots.txt. How can I do this?!
Is it correct to write: Dissallow: /*#*   or not?
I tried Disallow: *#  but unfortunately it blocked some of my important articles.
A person told me that you should block Google bots to not index these URLs that table of content plugin made, because your websites crawl budget waste. I want to block Google bots to not index URLs with this structure: example.com/#title1 or example.com/#title2

You cannot block crawling of fragment identifiers (# and everything after them) using robots.txt. Fragment identifiers are never crawled to begin with.
That part of the URL is client-side only. When making a request to your server, browsers and crawlers strip off the # and everything after it.  That means that crawling https://example.com/ and https://example.com/#how_to_do_something are the exact same thing. In both cases, client will fetch https://example.com/ from your server.
robots.txt is not meant to prevent search engines from indexing content, it can only control what URLs search engine crawlers are allowed to fetch from the server.  If you want to prevent these pages from getting indexed from search engines, you should use meta noindex tags instead.
